# Scala Regex enable Multiline option

Tags: regex, scala, multiline

I'm learning Scala, so this is probably pretty noob-irific.

I want to have a multiline regular expression.

In Ruby it would be:

```
MY_REGEX = /com:Node/m
```

My Scala looks like:

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""<com:Node>""")
```

Here's my match function:

```
def matchNode( value : String ) : Boolean = value match 
{
    case ScriptNode() => System.out.println( "found" + value ); true
    case _ => System.out.println("not found: " + value ) ; false
}
```

And I'm calling it like so:

```
matchNode( "<root>\n<com:Node>\n</root>" ) // doesn't work
matchNode( "<com:Node>" ) // works
```

I've tried:

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""<com:Node>?m""")
```

And I'd really like to avoid having to use java.util.regex.Pattern. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: cheers for formatting! didn't work for me

Comment: You have to leave a blank line above and below each code block.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a very common problem when first using Scala Regex.

When you use pattern matching in Scala, it tries to match the whole string, as if you were using "^" and "$" (and did not activate multi-line parsing, which matches \n to ^ and $).

The way to do what you want would be one of the following:

```
def matchNode( value : String ) : Boolean = 
  (ScriptNode findFirstIn value) match {    
    case Some(v) => println( "found" + v ); true    
    case None => println("not found: " + value ) ; false
  }
```

Which would find find the first instance of ScriptNode inside value, and return *that* instance as v (if you want the whole string, just print value). Or else:

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""(?s).*<com:Node>.*""")
def matchNode( value : String ) : Boolean = 
  value match {    
    case ScriptNode() => println( "found" + value ); true    
    case _ => println("not found: " + value ) ; false
  }
```

Which would print all all value. In this example, (?s) activates dotall matching (ie, matching "." to new lines), and the .* before and after the searched-for pattern ensures it will match any string. If you wanted "v" as in the first example, you could do this:

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""(?s).*(<com:Node>).*""")
def matchNode( value : String ) : Boolean = 
  value match {    
    case ScriptNode(v) => println( "found" + v ); true    
    case _ => println("not found: " + value ) ; false
  }
```

Comment: It may not be clear to skim-readers like myself, but the inclusion of `(?s)` is key here in regard to matching against multi-line strings. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

Comment: @Synesso your link is broken now.  here is the java 7 equivalent  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

Comment: The link by @Synesso is broken. New link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick and dirty addendum: the `.r` method on `RichString` converts all strings to `scala.util.matching.Regex`, so you can do something like this:

```
"""(?s)a.*b""".r replaceAllIn ( "a\nb\nc\n", "A\nB" )
```

And that will return

```
A
B
c
```

I use this all the time for quick and dirty regex-scripting in the scala console.

Or in this case:

```
def matchNode( value : String ) : Boolean = {

    """(?s).*(<com:Node>).*""".r.findAllIn( text ) match {

       case ScriptNode(v) => System.out.println( "found" + v ); true    

       case _ => System.out.println("not found: " + value ) ; false
    }
}
```

Just my attempt to reduce the use of the word `new` in code worldwide. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just a small addition, use tried to use the `(?m)` (Multiline) flag (although it might not be suitable here) but here is the right way to use it:

e.g. instead of

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""<com:Node>?m""")
```

use

```
val ScriptNode =  new Regex("""(?m)<com:Node>""")
```

But again the (?s) flag is more suitable in this question (adding this answer only because the title is "Scala Regex enable Multiline option")