# Scala Regex Multiple Block Capturing

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to capture parts of a multi-lined string with a regex in Scala.
The input is of the form:

```
val input = """some text
              |begin {
              |  content to extract
              |  content to extract
              |}
              |some text
              |begin {
              |  other content to extract
              |}
              |some text""".stripMargin
```

I've tried several possibilities that should get me the text out of the `begin {` `}` blocks. One of them:

```
val Block = """(?s).*begin \{(.*)\}""".r

input match {
  case Block(content) => println(content)
  case _ => println("NO MATCH")
}
```

I get a `NO MATCH`. If I drop the `\}` the regex looks like `(?s).*begin \{(.*)` and it matches the last block including the unwanted `}` and "some text". I checked my regex at rubular.com as with `/.*begin \{(.*)\}/m` and it matches at least one block. I thought when my Scala regex would match the same I could start using `findAllIn` to match all blocks. What am I doing wrong?

I had a look at [Scala Regex enable Multiline option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088554/scala-regex-enable-multiline-option) but I could not manage to capture all the occurrences of the text blocks in, for example, a `Seq[String]`.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199302/alex-neth) has said, when using pattern matching to extract fields from regular expressions, the pattern acts as if it was bounded (ie, using `^` and `$`). The usual way to avoid this problem is to use `findAllIn` first. This way:

```
val input = """some text
              |begin {
              |  content to extract
              |  content to extract
              |}
              |some text
              |begin {
              |  other content to extract
              |}
              |some text""".stripMargin

val Block = """(?s)begin \{(.*)\}""".r

Block findAllIn input foreach (_ match {
  case Block(content) => println(content)
  case _ => println("NO MATCH")
})
```

Otherwise, you can use `.*` at the beginning and end to get around that restriction:

```
val Block = """(?s).*begin \{(.*)\}.*""".r

input match {
  case Block(content) => println(content)
  case _ => println("NO MATCH")
}
```

By the way, you probably want a non-eager matcher:

```
val Block = """(?s)begin \{(.*?)\}""".r

Block findAllIn input foreach (_ match {
  case Block(content) => println(content)
  case _ => println("NO MATCH")
})
```

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: Alex, at this point, I'm not sure. I did so much with Regex, even extending the library, that I can't even recall what the library provides or not! For instance, I was going to write `Block findAllMatchesIn input map (_ group 0)`, when I discovered this method doesn't exist in the library as it is.

Comment: for(Block(content) <- Block findAllIn input) println(content)

Comment: Thanks, Ken. I should have thought of providing at least one for-comprehension example. And doing the pattern match on the LHS is clever.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a match, I believe there is a full match implicity required.  Your match is equivalent to:

```
val Block = """^(?s).*begin \{(.*)\}$""".r
```

It works if you add .* to the end:

```
val Block = """(?s).*begin \{(.*)\}.*""".r
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, but I have encountered this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the other answers, I wanted to point out the existence of [kantan.regex](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.regex), which lets you write the following:

```
import kantan.regex.ops._

// The type parameter is the type as which to decode results,
// the value parameters are the regular expression to apply and the group to
// extract data from.
input.evalRegex[String]("""(?s)begin \{(.*?)\}""", 1).toList
```

This yields:

```
List(Success(
  content to extract
  content to extract
), Success(
  other content to extract
))
```