# Scala regex: Inconsistency between findAll and match ... case

Tags: regex, scala

I have a Scala regex which does match with `pattern.findFirstMatchIn()` but not with a `match ... case` unpacking statement:

```
val pattern = "\"(\\d+?)\",\"(.*?)\",(.+)$".r
val line = "\"1795\",\"title\",\"desc"

println(pattern.findFirstMatchIn(line).isDefined)

val pattern2Unpacking = line match {
  case pattern( category_id, title, description) =>
    true
  case _ => false
}

println(pattern2Unpacking)
```

The line to match is `"1795","title","desc`   and the lack of a trailing quote is intentional.

Output is `true` and `false` rather than both `true`.

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691002/scala-regex-multiple-block-capturing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068328/scala-regex-match-and-split) but I cannot relate the solutions to my problem. Omitting the boundary matchers does not change anything.

What is going wrong here?

**Update following comments**

***Spoiler:** Part of the apparent weirdness reported in the following is explained by the fact that my data contains characters not displayed by IDE, which is something to watch out for in these situations. For an excellent in-depth explanation what is actually happening, see the accepted answer.*

Here is a screenshot from my IntelliJ. Code on top is copy paste from the link by @WiktorStribiżew. Code on the bottom is the one I based this post on. Output window is included in the screenshot. This is not a prank, and I find this a little scary.

**Update 2**

This is even better: http://ideone.com/KsIIc1

No, I neither fake screenshots nor did I hack ideone.com to play a prank.

[image]

Comment: I find this like `val line = """"356","789","Title","bla """` to be cause of being it `false` because you need to escape quotes.

Comment: Damn, with escaped quotes it works. The problem is: The line with the quotes is just my toy example in order to post a complete code. My real problem is with a line coming from a CSV and a more complicated regex, which I dumbed down for readability.

Comment: Still, why does the original line yield `true` on `pattern.findFirstMatchIn`?

Comment: I'm not sure - but notice that it doesn't really match what you want it to match - if you print the result of `pattern.findFirstMatchIn(line)`, it prints `Some("356","789","Title","bla)` (notice the quotes are included!) - perhaps that's a lead on what's going wrong here.

Comment: Bcause match is found like this `"356"` rest of the preceding quotes are not mathched.

Comment: Ok, back to square 1. I'm posting a properly escaped version of the problem that still fails in a sec.

Comment: @DCS: Can't you use `'` instead of `"` like this '"1795","title","desc ' ? In php it's convention. Might be in scala too.

Comment: @noob In scala, `'` is a char. Strings need double quotes. Also, the strings to match actually come from a (16 GB) CSV file which I cannot change.

Comment: I ran the updated code and I get `true` for both outputs. Same for both REPL and Intellij IDE.

Comment: http://ideone.com/wvuZgw

Comment: Ok, this is getting a bit scary. Posting a screenshot from my IntelliJ - never thought I would have to use screenshots to prove that I am not a liar. Above code is copy paste from @WiktorStribiżew link. Second code is the one I based this post on. Same code (to me), different result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please see my ideone link. Copy-paste from my IntelliJ.

Comment: I would appreciate people not down voting or asking to close a question just because it documents behavior that is not trivial to reproduce. I do my best to prove my point is an actual problem.

Comment: @DCS: In your Edit 2, there is a U+2028 (LINE SEPARATOR) right after "desc". If you remove it, the IDEONE demo you posted will return 2 trues. Just as an experiment: add `(?s)` at the start of your pattern and retry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's it! This is what I now think that happened: I made the code sample by editing an original long troublesome string from my CSV data down to something smaller for posting. Despite of the editing the character seems to have survived, and it does not show up in IntelliJ.

Comment: So, do you want to keep the question and me to post an answer? Is the question still valid?

Comment: Given how crazy the problem looks when you encounter it for the first time, I think an answer might help somebody who encounters something similar. It basically cost me an afternoon. My view is that an answer helps future SO users, but if you disagree I'm happy to delete the post.

Comment: I think the real reason is that the `$` in the 2 cases was treated differently. In the first case, it was *the end of the string, or right before the final newline*, and in the second case, it was treated as a `\z`, *the very end of the string*.

Comment: Well, I think this question is valid after delving a bit deeper. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here lies in how [`findFirstMatchIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@findFirstMatchIn(source:CharSequence):Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match]) uses the regex pattern: it does not use it as an *anchored* pattern while the `match` uses the *anchored* version. If you read the [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex), you will see that findFirst methods do not use anchored patterns.

Now, why did `findFirst` find a match if your original string contains a U+2028 (LINE SEPARATOR) character at the end and the `$` anchor is defined at the end of the pattern? It is because `$` can match at the end of the string, or right at the last newline at the end of the string (equal to [`\Z` anchor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES)):

> The end of the input but for the final [terminator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt), if any

When Scala anchors the regex, it seems to use a `\z` logic, and only matches at the very end of the string (although [reference says](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unanchored:scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex) it uses `^` and `$`).

So, there are two ways to fix the issue:

- Either add a `(?s)` DOTALL modifier to the beginning of your pattern ([demo](http://ideone.com/n6T0t5)):
  `val pattern = "(?s)\"(\\d+?)\",\"(.*?)\",(.+)$".r`
- Or use `.unanchored` when defining the regex pattern ([demo](http://ideone.com/pV3jA2)):
  `val pattern = "\"(\\d+?)\",\"(.*?)\",(.+)$".r.unanchored`