# How to regex information between tags?

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to use a regex pattern to get the information between a specific tag like this:

```
val input = """#<tag>
  Information 1
  Information 2
  Information 3
#</tag>""".stripMargin

val testPattern = """#<tag>(.*?)#<\/tag>""".r
testPattern.findAllIn(input) foreach { println(_) }
```

But this gives me unfortunately no match. Since I'm not a regex guru: What do I miss here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the backslash in the second string with triple quotes, do you?

Comment: It's probably not needed, but it shouldn't harm anything.

Answer (score 4):

Dot (`.`) will not match new lines by default. You can change this behaviour as follows:

```
val testPattern = """(?s)#<tag>(.*?)#</tag>""".r
```

Note the `(?s)`, which is an "[embedded flag expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)" that triggers the new behaviour.

Also, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088554/scala-regex-enable-multiline-option) may also hold some answers for related problems you may run into.