# Multiline regex capture in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to capture the content from a multiline regex. It doesn't match.

```
val text = """<p>line1 
    line2</p>"""

val regex = """(?m)<p>(.*?)</p>""".r

var result = regex.findFirstIn(text).getOrElse("")
```

Returns empty.

I put the m - flag for multiline but it doesn't seem to help in this case.

If I remove the line break the regex works.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088554/scala-regex-enable-multiline-option) but couldn't get it working.

How do I match the content between the `<p>` elements? I want everything between, also the line breaks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As general advice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags indicates it might be better not to use a regex to parse HTML in most cases.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to activate the dotall mode in scala, you must use `(?s)` instead of `(?m)`

`(?s)` means the dot can match newlines

`(?m)` means `^` and `$` stand for begining and end of lines

Comment: Yup... `(?m)` will change the behaviour of `^` and `$`. Confusing names ;)

Comment: @fge confusing but m = multi, s = single line.

Comment: Something that took me a little while to realize, and was necessary for my application: m and s are not mutually exclusive. You can have (?ms) and it'll work like you'd expect.

Answer (score 7):

In case it's not obvious at this point, "How do I match the content":

```
scala> val regex = """(?s)<p>(.*?)</p>""".r

scala> (regex findFirstMatchIn text).get group 1
res52: String = 
line1 
    line2
```

More idiomatically,

```
scala> text match { case regex(content) => content }
res0: String =
line1
    line2

scala> val embedded = s"stuff${text}morestuff"
embedded: String =
stuff<p>line1
    line2</p>morestuff

scala> val regex = """(?s)<p>(.*?)</p>""".r.unanchored
regex: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (?s)<p>(.*?)</p>

scala> embedded match { case regex(content) => content }
res1: String =
line1
    line2
```